# How to change values of objectId column in parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

This may be very foolish question but I really want to know

> Is it possible to change values of Column_Name objectId in parse.com?

If yes, then **how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

According to Parse.com [API reference](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/) there is a setter for objectId so you can change it.